# Computing interior of subset of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $L$ be the subset of those bounded functions $f$: $[-1, 1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for which $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists.

By the iterated limits theorem, this is a closed subset of $B([-1, 1])$ wrt. the topology of uniform convergence induced by $\left\| f\right\|:=\sup\limits_{x\in [0, 1]}\left| f(x)\right|$.

What is its interior/boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For $f\in L,$ consider $f + c\sin (1/x)$ for small $c.$

Comment: Thanks. I just needed someone to confirm that the interior is empty ;)